# How to post data using jQuery and php based on which buttin us clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following data coming from my DB.
[image: var_dump]

I then build a table with the data that looks like this:
[image: Output to the screen]

This is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th> Vacancy Number</th>
                <th> Vacancy Title</th>
                <th> Requirements</th>
                <th> Responsibilities</th>
                <th> Qualifications</th>
                <th> Closing Date</th>
                <th> Apply</th>
             <tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <?php
                <?php
                //Loop through the data
                foreach ($currentVacancies as $vacancy) {
                    $vacancyID = $vacancy->vacancyID;
                    $roleID = $vacancy->roleID;
                    $roleShortTitle = $vacancy->roleShortTitle;
                    $roleLongTitle = $vacancy->roleLongTitle;
                    $roleDescID = $vacancy->roleDescID;
                    $roleRequirements = $vacancy->roleRequirements;
                    $roleResponsibilities = $vacancy->roleResponsibilities;
                    $roleQualifications = $vacancy->roleQualifications;
                    $closeDate = $vacancy->closeDate;
                    $recruitementType = $vacancy->recruitementType;

                    //Check if the recruitement is internal, external or for both
                    /* The user can be:
                     *      Online and not signed in
                     *      Online and signed in
                     *      Online, signed in and not staff
                     *      Online, signed in and staff
                     * We need to check for all these
                     */

                    if($recruitementType === 'Both' || $recruitementType === 'External'){
                        //display the vacancies
                        ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td id="vacancyID">
                                <?php echo $vacancyID; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td id="roleLongTitle">
                                <?php echo $roleLongTitle; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td id="roleRequirements">
                                <?php echo $roleRequirements; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td id="roleResponsibilities">
                                <?php echo $roleResponsibilities; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td id="roleQualifications">
                                <?php echo $roleQualifications; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td id="closeDate">
                                <?php
                                    //Convert the mySQL date to PHP date
                                    echo convertToDate($closeDate);
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                // Have jQuery code to add a button                                 
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                    }

                }

                ?>
            </tbody>
```

When I click the button marked 1 on the image below I want to post that information to a new page using jQuery and if I click the button marked 2 I want to post that information to a new page.  I can't get the correct information when I click the buttons.  I used console.log to check what info I get when I click which button and the out put is as follows:
Button 1
[image: Button 1 Output]

Button 2:
[image]

My code to add the button and identify the clicks:

```
var applyForRole = {

init: function(config){
    this.config = config;
    this.bindEvents();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        url: '../../applyForRole.php',
        type: 'POST'
    });
},

bindEvents: function(){
    //Remove the Button
    this.config.btn.remove();
    this.config.applyBtn = $('<input type="button" value=" Apply " id="toggleButton" \>');
    this.config.applyBtn.insertAfter(this.config.closeDate);

    this.config.applyBtn.on('click', this.validateInput);
},

//Check input
validateInput: function(){
    var self = applyForRole;
    var vacancyID = self.config.vacancyID.text();
    var roleLongTitle = self.config.roleLongTitle.text();
    var closeDate = self.config.closeDate.text();
    var roleRequirements = self.config.roleRequirements.text();
    var roleResponsibilities = self.config.roleResponsibilities.text();
    var roleQualifications = self.config.roleQualifications.text();
    console.log(vacancyID);
    console.log(roleLongTitle);
    console.log(roleRequirements);
    console.log(roleResponsibilities);
    console.log(roleQualifications);
    console.log(closeDate);
    console.log($(this));

}

  };

//Initiate Object
applyForRole.init({
vacancyID: $('td#vacancyID'),
closeDate: $('td#closeDate'),
roleLongTitle: $('td#roleLongTitle'),
roleRequirements: $('td#roleRequirements'),
roleResponsibilities: $('td#roleResponsibilities'),
roleQualifications: $('td#roleQualifications'),
btn: $('a.btn-primary')
});
```

Can someone please help me so I can get the correct information based on the button I clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use id for not unique element, use class.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.toggleButton').click(function(){
            var obj = $(this).closest('tr');
            var data = {
                 vacancyID: obj.find('td.vacancyID').text(),
                 closeDate: obj.find('td.closeDate').text(),
                 roleLongTitle: obj.find('td.roleLongTitle').text(),
                 roleRequirements: obj.find('td.roleRequirements').text(),
                 roleResponsibilities: obj.find('td.roleResponsibilities').text(),
                 roleQualifications: obj.find('td.roleQualifications').text(),

                 }
                 console.log(data);
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th> Vacancy Number</th>
                <th> Vacancy Title</th>
                <th> Requirements</th>
                <th> Responsibilities</th>
                <th> Qualifications</th>
                <th> Closing Date</th>
                <th> Apply</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <?php
                <?php
                //Loop through the data
                foreach ($currentVacancies as $vacancy) {
                    $vacancyID = $vacancy->vacancyID;
                    $roleID = $vacancy->roleID;
                    $roleShortTitle = $vacancy->roleShortTitle;
                    $roleLongTitle = $vacancy->roleLongTitle;
                    $roleDescID = $vacancy->roleDescID;
                    $roleRequirements = $vacancy->roleRequirements;
                    $roleResponsibilities = $vacancy->roleResponsibilities;
                    $roleQualifications = $vacancy->roleQualifications;
                    $closeDate = $vacancy->closeDate;
                    $recruitementType = $vacancy->recruitementType;

                    //Check if the recruitement is internal, external or for both
                    /* The user can be:
                     *      Online and not signed in
                     *      Online and signed in
                     *      Online, signed in and not staff
                     *      Online, signed in and staff
                     * We need to check for all these
                     */

                    if($recruitementType === 'Both' || $recruitementType === 'External'){
                        //display the vacancies
                        ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="vacancyID">
                                <?php echo $vacancyID; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleLongTitle">
                                <?php echo $roleLongTitle; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleRequirements">
                                <?php echo $roleRequirements; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleResponsibilities">
                                <?php echo $roleResponsibilities; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleQualifications">
                                <?php echo $roleQualifications; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="closeDate">
                                <?php
                                    //Convert the mySQL date to PHP date
                                    echo convertToDate($closeDate);
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value=" Apply " class="toggleButton" \>                                    
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                    }

                }

                ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```